# Selectively apply middleware in express

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I have a route `/users` as a parent suffix in my router, all subsequent routes will append the the parent eg. `/users/details`

In my app.js

```
app.use('/api/v1/users', userRoutes);
```

In my userRoutes

```
import express from 'express';
import users from '../controllers/user_controller';

import { authenticateRoute, authenticateSignedRoute, aclAuthenticator } from './../middlewares/AuthenticationMiddleware';

const router = express.Router();


//user routes
router.get('/details', authenticateRoute, aclAuthenticator, users.getDetails);
router.get('/posts', authenticateRoute, aclAuthenticator, users.getPosts);


module.exports = router;
```

WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO DO

Is there a way for me to add the authenticateRoute and the aclAuthenticator middleware to the parent prefixed route, and then for one particular route have an exception where only a third middleware is applied and not the first two.

For eg
    app.use('/api/v1/users', authenticateRoute, aclAuthenticator, userRoutes);

My new router file

```
router.get('/details', applyOnlyThisMiddleWare, users.getDetails);
router.get('/posts', No MiddleWareAtAll, users.getPosts);
```

I'm basically trying to overide the initial middleware, is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

This is how i explicitly disable middleware for specific routes

```
'use strict';

const ExpressMiddleware = ( req, res, next ) => {

    // dont run the middleware if the url is present in this array
    const ignored_routes = [
        '/posts',
        '/random-url',
    ];

    // here i am checking for request method as well, you can choose to remove this
    // if( ! ignored_routes.includes(req.path) ) {
    if( req.method === 'GET' && ! ignored_routes.includes(req.path) ) {
        // do what you gotta do.
        // next();
    }
    else {
        next();
    }

}


export default ExpressMiddleware;
```

And in your server/routes file

```
app.use( ExpressMiddleware );
```

Ofcourse you might have to change the code, if you're using dynamic routes.. but that shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: @NitishPhanse Yes you can.

Comment: Also in this case how will you chain middlewares, if the condition is not met. Or should this check be added in each middleware

Comment: Just chain as you normally chain other middlewares, you can apply this globally as well, so the middleware will run for all routes and not for the excluded routes.. You can also do opposite so it will only run if the url is present in the array otherwise it will be ignored. Do what best suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of to do that is to apply the first two middlewares directly to your router with no path prefix:

```
router.use(middleware1, middleware2);
```

Then, in each of those middlewares, check the path of the URL and if it is the special path that you want to skip those middlewares for, then just call `next()`.

```
if (req.path.indexOf("/somepath") === 0) { return next() };
```

Then, you can register your third middleware only for the path you are interested in:

```
router.use("/somepath", middleware3);
```

The first two middewares will skip the ones you want them to skip and the third one will only get called for your specific route.

Comment: Wont this make the code really messy, route based checks create chaos. Also it'll have to be done via regex right. If i have a path `/user/1` this will keep changing right.?

Comment: @NitishPhanse - For what you described, it will be one added line of code in two routes (see line of code I added to my answer).  Route definitions are made to be inclusive, not exclusive so I don't know how else you would do it.  A cleaner way around it would be to fix your URL design so you don't create this situation in the first place, so that middleware3 is more easily separable from middleware1 and middleware2 (like on a whole separate router).

Comment: Completely agree with your point. I was just wondering if the exception list grows to say, 10 urls then i'll have to handle an array. What url structure do you propose that can handle this?

Comment: @NitishPhanse - If the URLs that require different middleware have a different path root, then it's easy to target separate middleware at them.  I don't know how your URLs/site are structured to offer something more specific than that.